# How to invoke telegram API to send pm to users?

Tags: java, telegram

I want to send pm messages via [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/#telegram-api) not with [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/#bot-api), but when I want to read related [documents](https://core.telegram.org/api/invoking) about how to make a request I actually do not understand any thing. Can anyone guide me how to start using [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/#telegram-api)?

Comment: Not clear question. Do you want to send PMs via Telegram App or via your own App with Telegram API? For information, I didn't find a solution for the first case yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short answer: there's a jave lib you can use (https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi)

Steps are very clear and straightforward(https://core.telegram.org/api#getting-started):

1- [Create yr application](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id)(register yrself for API usage):
[image]
API Key, Hash, configuration API will be generated for you

2- learn how to call APIs if you dont know there's a great course at codecademy (https://www.codecademy.com/apis)
you should know http concepts like get, post

3- authenticate yrself by auth_key_id and then using auth.sendCode method by passing auth_key_id, hash, phone_registered . steps are in https://core.telegram.org/api/auth

3- call telegram endpoints(https://core.telegram.org/methods). you can use some online tools to ease yr learning curve like https://www.hurl.it/

i have to admit since there's no code samples, it's not easy to use this API but steps are easy and it takes only some time.

hope it helps

Comment: I want to send message on user's telegram, when user registers on my website. How to do that?

Comment: @DevendraSingh have u tried [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage)

Comment: @DevendraSingh there is no solution for your case yet.